# MongoDB FindOne function doesn't return any data

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I have a struct

```
type User struct {
    uuiduser string `json:"id"`
    avatar_image string `json:"avatar_img"`
    avatar_type string `json:"avatar_type"`
    name string `json:"name"`
    surname string `json:"surname"`
    datastart string `json:"datastart"`
    login string `json:"login"`
    pass string `json:"pass"`
}
```

And I have a code, that use official MongoDB API for Go. tHis code must return value of document.

```
var result User

    err := users.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{}).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result.login)
    return result.login
```

But it doesn't - each part of result are nil.
InsertOne() also doesn't work - it just creates a new empty document.
Of course, no errors are returned. Where I have a mistake?

Comment: You must export struct fields. Start them with capital letter, e.g. `Name`, `AvatarType`.

Comment: Multiple issues with this : 
1.) your struct fields are not exported, 2.) FindOne need a filter document with query operators and 3.) Your InsertOne() needs to be successful before calling FindOne(). Can you share you InsertOne() code as well ? Are the User struct and the FindOne() call in the same package ?

Comment: You are both right - when I changed struct fields names to start with a capital letter - it works fine. Actually it's strange because I think that when you struct is in another package, you need to do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@icza and @Kartavya are both right - when I changed struct fields names to start with a capital letter - it works fine. Actually it's strange because I think that when you struct is in another package, you need to do this. Thanks :)

Comment: Your struct is defined in _your_ package. When you pass your struct to `mongo-go`, then the declaring package (your package) is another package for the `mongo-go` driver. So you need to export fields to allow the driver to access / change its fields.